# PHP hardlink non-English characters path

Tags: php

How can I hardlink a file inside the non-English directory?

```
function createDir($path) {
  if (!file_exists($path)) {
    createDir(dirname($path));
    mkdir($path, 0777);
  }
}

createDir(__DIR__.'/data2xml/南海釣魚台');

$src = "D:\\xampp\htdocs\\projectb/data1/pic/2003161613561.jpg";
$dest = "D:\\xampp\htdocs\\projectb/data2xml/南海釣魚台/2003161613561.jpg";

link($src, $dest);
```

> Warning: link(): No error in D:\xampp\htdocs\projectb\test.php on line 17
>
> link ( ???, ??? ) ...\test.php:17

copy($src, $dest) can work but it takes too much time.

test.php works fine on the other win10 machines. How can I debug this?
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you mixing backslashes and forward slashes?

Comment: D:\xampp\htdocs\projectb = ＿DIR＿

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Moving a file is faster than copying a file.

rename() can work on non-English characters.

Hardlink to a English temp file and then move it to the destination.

```
$tmp = __DIR__.'/tmpfile';
link($src, $tmp);
rename($tmp, $dest);
```

or upgrade to php7.2.7+

https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.2.7

Fixed bug #76335 ("link(): Bad file descriptor" with non-ASCII path).

Comment: What does that mean? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it